# Facebook Graph API - How to loop through all albums

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK with Laravel and I need to loop through all photos in all albums and I'm struggling a little!

What I have at the minute is:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
      'GET',
      '/{username}/photos'
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    print_r($graphObject);
```

this outputs JSON which I can't seem to find an easy way to loop and pull out the source for all the images. Does the SDK have some nice functions to grab the images for me?

Cheers,

Nick

Comment: It returns array of Photos object, and you can look at the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo) to see available fields and their types.